# Android SDK manager cannot access repository: permission denied

Tags: sdk, permission-denied

I initially didn't have issues with accessing the repository and installing packages through the SDK manager.  However, somehow it does and I haven't figured out the reason yet. The following message appears on the Android SDK Manager Log:

Failed to fetch URL http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml, reason: Permission denied: connect
....
Failed to fetch URL http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-8.xml, reason: Socket Permission denied: connect
Done loading packages.

I took the following actions but none have worked

1. checked the box "force https://.. sources to be fetched from
   http://"
2. Ran Android SDK manager exe file as an administrator
3. launched the command prompt and ran android.bat command in the
   ../sdk/tools directory and this is what I got INFO: I/O exception
   (java.net.SocketException) caught when connecting to the target
   host:Permission denied
4. reinstalled adt bundle to a different
   directory
5. uninstalled and then reinstalled Java JRE and JDK
6. disabled firewall and avg antivirus.  I don't think it's an issue
   since if I can access the repository page through the internet
   browser
7. tried at a different location (coffee shop)

Please advise if you have experienced something similar or if the android sdk manager can be bypassed together.

About my laptop:

I'm running on windows 8, 64-bit

ADT Build: v22.3.0-887826 which is extracted to the following directory C:\development
Android SDK manager version 22.3

Java version 7 update 51

Answer (score 0):

Change **http** i your URL to **https** and try. Probably it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to edit the android.bat and added the statement:

```
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

directly after

> call %java_exe%

so it will become:

```
call %java_exe% -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true %REMOTE_DEBUG% -Dcom.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir="%tools_dir%" -Dcom.android.sdkmanager.workdir=%work_dir% -classpath "%jar_path%;%swt_path%\swt.jar" com.android.sdkmanager.Main %*
```

This helped a lot of people.

See also: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=41231#c6

Comment: Thanks but I tried this solution before and sdk manager wouldn't start.

Comment: Ok, does it work, if you disable this Add-On-Site via Tools -> Manage Add-on Sites...?

Comment: Nice to hear! In your position i would update the question text and append the solution could be helpful for others